# Blank space between Tabbar and webview - iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios7

I am using webview getting trouble in iOS7 . its show the blank space between my webview and the tabbar.
Following is the my Sceen-shots and code. Please help me on this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rectFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    self.view.frame = rectFrame;
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    // demoWebview is my Webview 
    demoWebView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    demoWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    demoWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(onBack:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [backButton release];

}
```

Comment: you have to to execute your URL in Browser first may be default blank space is already there..

Comment: @Dipen : I am not loading any external url here, iused embed code for youtube video here

Comment: remove this and check demoWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES; if it doesn't work show the code you written for loading youtube video in web view please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem to adding following code :

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) 
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```